# Ruby - Divide the number of users into groups of sizes 3, 4 or 5

Tags: ruby

I am writing an app that requires me to divide a given number of users into two or more groups, each containing 3, 4 or 5 users. There can be any number of users greater than 8.

For instance, 11 users can be divided into 3 groups, of sizes 4, 4 and 3, which I will designate [4,4,3]. Other examples are as follows.

- [3,3,3] for 9 users
- [5,5] for 10 users
- [3,3,3,3] for 12 users
- [5,4,3] for 12 users
- [5,5,3] for 13 users
- [5,5,4] for 14 users
- [3,3,3,5] for 14 users
- [5,5,5] for 15 users
- [4,4,4,3] for 15 users

How can I obtain any collection of any number of groups of users, with each group containing 3, 4 or 5 users, such that the sum of the group sizes equals a given number of users?

Comment: 12 could also be `[5,4,3]` or `[3,3,3,3]`. Are there any addition rules that would lead to `[4,4,4]`?

Comment: You are right, it can be done in that way. nope, there are not any rules. it just min 3 and max 5 rule.

Comment: BTW, _"in groups of 3, 4 or 5"_ and _"into 3, 4 or 5 groups"_ is quite a difference. The former refers to the number of elements in each group whereas the latter refers to the number of groups. You might want to clarify.

Comment: Why are the group sizes for 13 employees 5, 5, 3 and not 3, 5, 5 or 5, 3, 5 or 5, 4, 4 or 4, 5, 4 or 4, 4, 5 or 3, 3, 3, 4 or 3, 3, 4, 3 or 3, 4, 3, 3 or 4, 3, 3, 3? Why not 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 for 15? Why not 3, 3, 3, 3 for 12?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the in_groups method and it’s implementation from Ruby on Rails: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups

Comment: Vishal, I trust that my edit is an accurate statement of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minimize the number of groups**

```
def groupem(n)
  raise ArgumentError if n < 9
  m = n/5
  case n%5
  when 0
    [5]*m
  when 1
    [5]*(m-1) << 3 << 3
  when 2
    [5]*(m-1) << 4 << 3
  when 3
    [5]*m << 3
  else # 4
    [5]*m << 4
  end
end
```

```
groupem(8)
  #=> ArgumentError

(9..20).each { |n| puts "#{n.to_s.rjust(2)} users: #{groupem(n)}" }
 9 users: [3, 3, 3]
10 users: [3, 3, 4]
11 users: [5, 3, 3]
12 users: [5, 4, 3]
13 users: [5, 5, 3]
14 users: [5, 5, 4]
15 users: [5, 5, 5]
16 users: [5, 5, 3, 3]
17 users: [5, 5, 4, 3]
18 users: [5, 5, 5, 3]
19 users: [5, 5, 5, 4]
20 users: [5, 5, 5, 5]
```

**Maximize the number of groups**

```
def groupem(n)
  raise ArgumentError if n < 9
  m = n/3
  case n%3
  when 0
    [3]*m
  when 1
    [3]*(m-1) << 4
  else # 2
    [3]*(m-1) << 5
  end
end
```

```
groupem(8)
  #=> ArgumentError

(9..20).each { |n| puts "#{n.to_s.rjust(2)} users: #{groupem(n)}" }
 9 users: [3, 3, 3]
10 users: [3, 3, 4]
11 users: [3, 3, 5]
12 users: [3, 3, 3, 3]
13 users: [3, 3, 3, 4]
14 users: [3, 3, 3, 5]
15 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
16 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
17 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 5]
18 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
19 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
20 users: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5]
```